# Activeadmin - undefined method `batch_action'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm trying to use activeadmin's batch_action so I can run actions on more than one record. However when trying to run my rails server I get the following error.

```
undefined method `batch_action' for #<ActiveAdmin::ResourceDSL:0xb11f980> (NoMethodError)
```

Here is the activeadmin resource code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product do

batch_action :destroy, false

filter :name

index do
    selectable_column
  column :name
  default_actions
end

controller do
    def current_company
        @current_company
    end
end

end
```

I'm not sure where I'm getting it wrong - I need to show a corresponding checkboxes against the records and then define a batch action. Where am I getting it wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer :) was a wrong entry in my gemfile.

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1302